# Casper.js to fill out browser username and password?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs, casperjs

Some case a website would ask username and password in this form (attached photo below) from the browser. Is it possible to use Casper.js to fill out this?

Casper.fill can only do it when it's a HTML form.
http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.fill

[image]

UPDATE 1:

I tried this and didn't work.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
      pageSettings: {
        userName: "myusername",
        password: "mypassword"
      }
    });
```

This login box is in Windows 7 and the reason it popped up because I used proxy. And the reason I have to do this is because `casperjs --proxy=x.x.x.x --proxy-auth=u:p` don't work (at least on Win7)

Comment: Take a look at the pageSettings.userName and pageSettings.password options [here](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.options)

Comment: It didn't work. I tried and updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshot, it seems that you are dealing with HTTP Basic Authentication. If that's the case then you should be able to use the following url format:

http://username:password@www.example.com/path

[Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Though, I did not test if it works in CasperJS

Comment: This is for proxy. Normal proxy command line doesn't work in Casperjs Windows for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`setHttpAuth()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#sethttpauth) function for this:

```
var casper = require("casper").create();
casper.start();

casper.setHttpAuth('sheldon.cooper', 'b4z1ng4');

casper.thenOpen('http://password-protected.domain.tld/', function() {
    this.echo("I'm in. Bazinga.");
});

casper.run();
```